# Is it possible to execute vb.net code using vs2010 without running the project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ide

This may be a strange question and have no answer but I thought I would post it to see how you would go about doing it. I have a line of code:

```
Grade = Math.Round((Math.Abs(CorrectAnswers) / TotalQuestions) * 100)
```

Basically that line just figures out the grade no major code work there, what I want to do is execute that specific line with different variables without running the whole application and navigating to the point in the application which for this segment would be completing a 150 question exam, or coding some #temp page and running it from there.

I am trying to track a bug in the code that happens very rarely (you know when the planets in the universe are out of cosmic alignment) and I think my issue lies with this subset and I am trying to find a better/easier way of testing it.

Comment: The ONLY thing I miss about VB6 is the Immediate Window. You could create objects and run lines like this really easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a Class Diagram item to the project and from Solution Explorer you drag the class file which contains the method into it, you can invoke static methods (right click on the Class element or use Class Diagram Menu). 
It will ask you the values for the arguments.
And really you do can use Immediate window (Ctrl+G or Debug->Windows menu)
Open it and type:
CorrectAnswers=25.5
TotalQuestions=30
?Math.Round((Math.Abs(CorrectAnswers) / TotalQuestions) * 100)
And you'll get:
85.0 {Double}
    Double: 85.0
Tip: type >cls to clear the immediate window contents.
I don't understand how Bill says he misses it from VB6. We have it too at VisualStudio and fully functional :)
Regards.
ps:I translate from the spanish 2008 version so you could have other menu options, hotkeys, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will have to try this out today.

Answer (score 2):

You could extract this into a method, that takes the values needed as parameters, then create a test harness to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

So there are 150 questions, and they can either be right or wrong? Which means there are only 151 possible inputs? Why not just calculate them all? Run this in a console application and see whether you like the results.

```
  Sub Main()
    Dim Grade As Integer
    Const TotalQuestions = 150
    Console.WriteLine("Marks             Grade")
    For CorrectAnswers = 0 To 150
      Grade = Math.Round((Math.Abs(CorrectAnswers) / TotalQuestions) * 100)
      Console.WriteLine(Format(CorrectAnswers, "000") & " out of 150 => " & _
                         Format(Grade, "000"))
    Next CorrectAnswers
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub
```

Be aware that Math.Round uses *banker's rounding* by default. If the fractional component of a is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, then the even number is returned. [You can change this behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8.aspx).